# 'paymentWithProductIdentifier' is deprecated

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have simply problem with

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"ident"];
```

The problem is that paymentWithProductIdentifier is deprecated.
I found on the internet that I can use

```
paymentWithProduct
```

But the problem is that I don't know how to get SKProduct.

I wrote something like this:

```
SKProductsResponse *response;
SKProduct *validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:validProduct];
```

But it doesn't work.
Where is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code uses *response without initializing it - that is the immediate problem.

However, the bigger issues is getting the SKProduct object.  The basic method here is that before presenting the ability to purchase items to the user, you need to put a request into the App Store to retrieve the SKProduct objects you may want to show the user.  Each SKProduct contains the localized price and description information you need to present to the user.  I structure my code to retrieve the product array on entry to the buy screen.  Depending on your app, you may need to call it earlier.

You start with the skus of a list of possible purchaseable items.  Then create an SKProductsRequest object using that set of skus (SKProductsRequest initWithProductIdentifiers:).  Also, supply an SKProductsRequestDelegate to receive the response. Then start the request. When it calls into the delegate using didReceiveResponse:, you can save the array in the response containing the SKProduct objects.  It also returns a list of invalid products that you cannot present to the user.  Only present items for which you have received an SKProduct object in the callback.

When it comes time to actually initiate the payment, you pull the correct SKProduct object from the array passed into the SKProductsRequestDelegate didReceiveResponse: method to create the payment object.

Comment: Well, everything I have there. I just showed the code where I have a problem.

Comment: If you have all of this, then why are you using paymentWithProductIdentifier: instead of paymentWithProduct:?